# nginx location /sub/$VAR/ to proxy_pass /sub/$VAR/

Tags: variables, nginx, proxy, location

I've tried several things to accomplish this. Even writing a new serverblock for each port/client.

I'm busy launching an application which users can rent for an n amount of hours, because each instance is launched on it's own port, i would like to give users an url that forwards them to their own instance of the application based on the port number for example.

What i have now, just for testing

```
location /go/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
    proxy_redirect off;
}

location /go/5001/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001/;
    proxy_redirect off;
}


location ^~ /status/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/status;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

What i would like to achieve, that the var being passed (for example 5006) is passed to the proxy_pass port. Also, for each instance, i would like a /status/ to see the status (and should i use end / ? .. i tried it without them, but sometimes its loading the path including an ending / , sometimes it even replaces the url to 127.0.0.1:port, and sometimes it loads without css/images/js.

```
location /go/$VAR/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$VAR/;
    proxy_redirect off;
}


location /go/$VAR/status/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$VAR/status;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to capture a port from the URI and use it in the `proxy_pass` statement, you can use a regular expression location with a named capture.

For example (and I have not tested this):

```
location ~ ^/go/(?<myport>\d+)(?<myuri>/.*)$ {
    rewrite ^ $myuri break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$myport;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! i'll try this first thing tomorrow morning. something tells me this is the correct pattern. Will let you know if it worked. thanks again!

Comment: Awsome! Works almost perfectly. I was looking a long time for this. Thank you!

Only thing is, i can access the app through /go/5001/ but not through /go/5001  

while subdirs like /go/5001/status are only accessible without ending slash 

Thanks again for your answer! It already saves me a lot of extra hassle